# What is industry standards/best practices for a user's personal drive on the network?

Tags: networking

I have been recently tasked with cleaning up some network drives and discovered that there is no order, just utter chaos. I have also found there are 54,000 duplicate files resulting in an extra 30GB of space being wasted, for no apparent reason. When I inquired what the system was, I was informed that many users place his or her data in their personal drive. I asked what the limitations on those drives and discovered that they had unlimited space requirements. I'd like to know what are some Best Practices in this area are. I have seen500MB and unlimited. I'd like to hear your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: The question is too broad as stated. What's your problem?

Comment: There are no standards.  Duplication isn't necessarily bad.  Spend less time worrying about 30GB.  That is like $0.25 worth of storage these days?

Comment: `resulting in an extra 30GB of space being wasted, for no apparent reason.`  I have that much "wasted space," in duplicated files on my computer's system drive.  Don't worry about until it's actually a problem, like when you start to run out of space of $server or $SAN.  And even then, the right solution is usually to buy more disk.

Comment: Let's try this, What size should users personal drive be on the network?

Comment: @Richard depends on how good the stuff they store on it is.  If the user stores really good porn that I like on their personal drive, I give them unlimited space.  If they just store bad porn, or business documents, I don't give them any space, because I don't want to see that.

Answer (score 5):

There is no single best practice, because every company is different.

- Some companies have strong rules about this stuff from a compliance perspective.
- Some companies have strong rules about this stuff from a cost perspective.
- Some companies have lax rules about this stuff because they aren't as concerned about those things  - rightly or wrongly.

That said, you have to understand why you were asked with cleaning up network drives, what the goal is, and how much discretion you have in changing (or simply enforcing) policy, if there is any.

/Edited based on your added comment: "What size should users personal drive be on the network" That's even more difficult to answer because that's dependent on the above things, PLUS what the business actually does. If it's a graphic design company without a lot of collaboration, the answer is ZOMG HUGE because they need to have prepress graphics, raw image files, etc. If they do a lot of collaboration, maybe it's just a little because everything should be in shared storage space.

And that's just one quick example. The question cannot be answered in general terms. The only proper answer is "It depends." Without any details, I can't even begin to answer the question for you, only give you some pointers on how to find the best answer for your company.

Answer (score 3):

Richard, hopefully you haven't taken any offense with the comments to your question but this is a question that can't really be answered by anyone but you and your company. What is best practice? Whatever meets the needs and objectives of your company. We can't tell you that.

30GB is a drop in the bucket these days, so the fact that duplicate files are consuming 30GB of storage space wouldn't even spark a conversation in most organizations.

What you should do is have a conversation with whomever tasked you with this to define what best practice should be for your organization and to determine what the end result should be. When they tell you to "clean up" the network drives, what do the mean specifically? What are they envisioning as the end result?

Comment: Thank you and no I haven't taken offense. I am just curious to hear what other companies do to get a baseline. Right now, I am gathering facts and then sharing my results whether they are 500MB or unlimited space. I realize that storage is cheap; however users are storing working documents on his or her personal drives and not using the latest or greatest. Thanks again.